# type a generic comparator function with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that shold return me another function to compare two objects by a specified key, like this:

```js
function compareTexts(text1: string, text2: string, caseSensitive = false): 0 | -1 | 1 {
    const t1 = (caseSensitive ? text1 : text1.toLowerCase()).trim();
    const t2 = (caseSensitive ? text2 : text2.toLowerCase()).trim();

    return t1 === t2 ? 0 : t1 < t2 ? -1 : 1;
}

function compareByProp(prop: string) {
    return (a: any, b: any) => compareTexts(a[prop], b[prop]);
}
```

(see typescript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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) with example)

I'd like to get rid of the `any` types, and return a function that would only accept object with the `prop` key in it.

like this:

```js
// this should be OK
console.log( compareByProp('name')({ name: 'sas', age: '2' }, { name: 'aaa', age: '5' })) 

// this should err, because objects don't have the `agex` property
console.log( compareByProp('agex')({ name: 'sas', age: '2' }, { name: 'aaa', age: '5' }))
```

I tried withi this:

```js
function compareByProp(prop: string) {
    return (a: { [prop]: string }, b: { [prop]: string }) => compareTexts(a[prop], b[prop]);
}
```

But I get the following error: `A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.(1170)`

Any idea how to achieve it, or a better approach to handle it?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wo549N) work for you? We're just using a generic to "store" what was passed and then use that to create the type for `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a generic to describe the property:

```
function compareByProp<TProp extends PropertyKey>(prop: TProp) {
    return (a: { [k in TProp]: string }, b: { [k in TProp]: string }) => compareTexts(a[prop], b[prop]);
}
```

Note that `PropertyKey` is just a standard alias for `string | number | symbol` which are the supported key types.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my own solution

First attemp:

```
function comparator_bad<T, K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
    return (a: T, b: T) => a[key] === b[key] ? 0 : (a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : -1)
}
```

This doesn't catch the case where the key is missing in either a or b

While this version

```
function comparator_ok<T extends {[key in K]: unknown}, K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
    return (a: T, b: T) => a[key] === b[key] ? 0 : (a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : -1)
}
```

Works fine (I still can't quite understand the difference between `keyof T` and `[key in K]` it seems

Here's a complete example:

```
function comparator_bad<T, K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
    return (a: T, b: T) => a[key] === b[key] ? 0 : (a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : -1)
}

function comparator_ok<T extends {[key in K]: unknown}, K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
    return (a: T, b: T) => a[key] === b[key] ? 0 : (a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : -1)
}

let items = [
    { name: 'aaa', age: 99 },
    { name: 'ccc', age: 42, color: 'black' },
    { name: 'bbb', age: 40 },
]

console.log({ by_age_with_comparator_bad: items.sort(comparator_bad('age')) })
console.log({ by_age_with_comparator_ok: items.sort(comparator_ok('age')) })

// no problem for ts in here :-(
console.log({ by_color_with_comparator_bad: [...items].sort(comparator_bad('color')) })

// with this this one ts complains!
console.log({ by_color_with_comparator_ok: [...items].sort(comparator_ok('color')) })

/*
error:

Argument of type '(a: { color: unknown; }, b: { color: unknown; }) => 0 | 1 | -1' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 
'(
  a: { name: string; age: number; color?: undefined; } | 
     { name: string; age: number; color: string; }, 
  b: { name: string; age: number; color?: undefined; } | 
     { name: string; age: number; color: string; }
) => number'.

  Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.

    Type '
      { name: string; age: number; color?: undefined; } | 
      { name: string; age: number; color: string; }' 
    is not assignable to type '{ color: unknown; }'.
  
      Type '{ name: string; age: number; color?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ color: unknown; }'.
  
        Property 'color' is optional in type '{ name: string; age: number; color?: undefined; }' but required in type '{ color: unknown; }'.
*/
```

see [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbADgQwE6anbAfQCNMATAHgBUAaRAaUQFMAPKJsMgZ0QGsmAnnGCIqAPgAU-AQC4GASkQBvAFCJ1ibEyghsSCZjm1ExI4oC8YxJgDa0gLqJzzk3cGOA-IgAMiOQbcBRytiQM9EAEY-RABaCPkVAF8VFVBIWARkNCxcfCI4XmpmNg5uZUDEGCR6ezlwXjA4AHcwRLpGVnZOHmlhUUlpOXpFVQ1NbV19Q1E6U1ELK1sHJxdQ5a9ffyX3RBCwxC8ouTiE5JUAG21K9lQec0QbNQ0lRDBMVCY5AHJMX6+6TAAc0+iAAnKDEG0nuoXm8Pt8IIj-tZgXIACwAJjoKHOBG+xHOmAgvC+kJo0OUr3eIK+xDpyKBILRvih9hSKDAXDglwAdLjARIXsQBIRGYQmjAoAALQgoDA4PAEEjkOSSpi3Hlc7BQCRynKKoikMgSH7Ar7yRSJBIcrm8-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-PTYMaeDhti9QKXUcrvy6kKLN4uq+ts0TxNa1z2sSEbcPGoiSMwMiZrmirFpgxygJWsC1qeTaNAABWvL9tQEJjqyuuB0AyN5zgKp6dqpLyfKG3qAsa+zTpctzhpMEBXy0ABHEAYC0MgYYYuGALeuDPsu2LT3rIA)